# Some fields from realm object are null when try to get object from DB

Tags: android, database, kotlin, realm

Some fields like "long" from geoLocation object is null when try to get object from DB.
Here is the real object.

```
Object{
id:"232342346823482348"
fields: [{
   location:{
             city:"",
             houseNo:"",
             state:"",
             geoLocation: { 
                          lat="23.000000", 
                          long="54.00000"
             }
   }
}]
}
```

And where i try to get object from DB.

```
   override fun insertOrUpdateObject(object: Object) {
        realm.executeTransaction {
            realm.where(Object::class.java).contains("id", object.id).findAll()
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the data exist in the db?

Comment: Have you seen your model class data when you are inserting in DB.

Comment: @NikhilGupta object is insered in DB

Comment: @kundankamal yes and the "long" field is populated

Comment: are you sure about `.contains("id", object.id)` ? It should be with `equalTo` and a `find` instead of `findAll` no ? `Can you provide class declaration and how you deserialize and insert data plz ?